# How to trigger gitlab job if cache empty?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

### Background

Consider a dummy gitlab job with a `prebuild` and `build` stage.

```
stages:
  - prebuild
  - build
```

The sole job of the `prebuild` stage is to create and cache dependencies for later stages.  The `prebuild` stage is only triggered if a python `requirements.txt` file changes.  The `build` stage has a `cache:policy` of `pull`, meaning it defers to `prebuild` for the cache.  For example, imagine the cache consisted of a shared a single file `sharedfile`:

```
prebuild_job:
   cache:
     policy: pull-push
     rules:
       - changes:
         - requirements.txt
     paths:
       - sharedfile
     script:
       - echo "FOOBAR" > sharedfile

build_job:
   cache:
     policy: pull
   paths:
     - sharedfile
   script:
     - cat sharedfile
```

This does what I want - `prebuild` is triggered only when `requirements.txt` changes and `build` uses its output (in this case `sharedfile` but in reality a full python virtual env.).
This works great until the cache is manually cleared on gitlab via the **Clear Runner Caches** button, then we have to manually re-run the prebuild step or builds will keep failing as the prebuild was never retriggered after the cache clear.

[image]

### Question

How can we setup a [rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules-clauses) or workaround such that the `prebuild_job` will know to fire if the cache is empty in addition to its existing change rule?.  Something like

```
prebuild_job:
   cache:
     policy: pull-push
     rules:
       - changes:
         - requirements.txt
       - if: "$CACHE == {}"     #<-- something like this
     paths:
       - sharedfile
     script:
       - echo "FOOBAR" > sharedfile
```

### Workaround

Can add an optional button to retrigger the prebuild phase manually.  `allow_failure` means the button is optional and won't block subsequent stages.

```
prebuild_job:
   cache:
     policy: pull-push
     rules:
       - changes:
         - requirements.txt
       - if: '"True"'
         when: manual
         allow_failure: true     
       ...
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I don't think I ever looked into it further after posting the question...